# Why sometimes can not call a function after save on modal?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, modal-dialog, laravel-5.3

My modal is like this :

```
<div id="modal-account" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            {!! Form::open(['url' => 'member/profile/setting/account/add','class'=>'form-horizontal']) !!}
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                                aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Add</h4>
                </div>
                ...

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
                </div>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

My routes is like this :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth', 'prefix'=>'member', 'as'=>'member.'], function () {
     ...
     Route::group(['prefix' => 'profile', 'as'=>'profile.'], function () {
         ...
         Route::get('setting/account', 'Member\UserBankController@create');
         Route::post('setting/account/add', 'Member\UserBankController@store');
         ...
     });
     ...
});
```

My controller is like this :

```
public function store(CreateUserBankRequest $request)
{
    dd('test');
    ...
}
```

When the first time I run the modal, and then click the submit button, it successfully runs the statements in the store function, which displays the word : `test`.

But after that, I tried again the second and so on, it can not display the word : `test`.

Sometimes it can be. Sometimes it can not.

Whether there are any people who can explain, why it happened and what is the solution?